# jquery php assign css values dynamically

Tags: php, jquery, css

i have some images in an un ordered list.

```
<ul>
    <li id='chain'>
        <a href="">
            <span class='fade'></span>
            <div class='title'>TITLE</div>
            <img src="img/bike/chain.jpg" alt="" width="550" height="440" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id='grips'>
        <a href="">
            <span class='fade'></span>
            <div class='title'>TITLE</div>
            <img src="img/bike/grips.jpg" alt="" width="275" height="440" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li id='tires'>
        <a href="">
            <span class='fade'></span>
            <div class='title'>TITLE</div>
            <img src="img/bike/tires.jpg" alt="" width="175" height="220" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

i need css that will give the span and div in each set the same width like this expressed in a loop, NOT hand written every item

```
#chain .fade,   #chain .title {width:550px}
#grips .fade,   #grips .title {width:275px}
#tires .fade,   #tires .title {width:175px;}
```

question: could i dynamically create css using jQuery? if not how can i create this css and assign the width value using PHP?
the list items will change often and i wish to use a loop or .each statement.
in other words i dont want to make a list of each item
is there a way to pull the li ID and the IMG dimension and dynamically create css

pseudo code:

```
var w = $('ul li').each(find img width).assign it to> .css(this .fade, this .title {width:w + "px"});
```

or
should i look into php to echo the output of each ul li IMG?

Comment: Is it even necessary to do this though? If you assign a `width: 100%` to `.fade` and `.title`, float the `<li>`s to shrink-wrap them and let the image size set the width of the `<li>` it should just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how to do it with jQuery:

```
$('li').each(function(){
    var $li = $(this);   
    var $img = $li.find('img');
    var width = $img.attr('width');
    $li.find('.fade, .title').css('width', width + 'px');
});
```

**Or get rid of the jQuery, and use just css:**

```css
​li { float: left; clear: left; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u2HNx/2/

Comment: but can this be done with a loop or some type of automation?  i dont want to write a long list of items that change

Comment: Sure, but I don't know what you're looking for.

Comment: without creating a list of each list item,  how would you write this

Comment: @t q: I'm afraid you can't create automate this without providing some sort of 'handle' for the automation; you'll have to figure out a way to name your class and IDs such that you'll have some way to iterate over them.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How do you know which `<li>` contents get which width?

Comment: thats my question, is there a way to pull the li ID and the IMG dimension and dynamically create css

Answer (score 2):

jQuery easily allows you to create inline CSS styles (styles that are applied to each element).

```
$('#chain, #grips, #tires').each(function(index, element){
  $('.fade', element).width( $('img', element).width() );
});
```

**Here is what this script is doing**

`.each()` iterates over all the selected elements. `index`, as the name suggests, is the index of the array being iterated over. `element` is the current element being iterated over.

`$('.fade', element)` this looks for the class of `fade` within the element.

`.width()` will either get or set the width of an element. It will be set if a parameter is passed into it, example: `.width(15)`. (This will set the width of the element to 15 pixels wide.) It retrieves the width of an element if nothing is passed into it, example: `.width()`.

`$('img', element).width()` retrieves the width of the img tag inside the element. Because this value is being passed into `$('.fade', element).width()`, it will set elements with the class of fade to width of the img.

Answer (score 0):

ok, try this:

```
  $('li').each(function(){
       var width = $(this).find('IMG').width();
       $(this).find('.fade').width(width);
       $(this).find('.title').width(width);
    });
```

Comment: this would be the same as writing out the css

Comment: what you mean about pull the li ID and the IMG dimension?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#chain .fade,#chain .title").css('width','550px');
```